# Breaking change in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4? Media player with smooth streaming

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml, media-player, smooth-streaming-player

I used to have a my mediaplayer that used to work with my smooth streaming urls, however since i have updated my visual studio 2013 to Update 4 i get the following error => **MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0xC00D36C4** 
Does anyone have this problem?

I have tried to remove the following dll and readd them: [image]

However this has done nothing